# JPQL Date between interval

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpql

Where is my error?

```
SELECT m FROM Message m WHERE m.tabId = :idTab AND BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate ORDER BY m.id DESC
```

I've this error:

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query ... , line 1, column 63: unexpected token [BETWEEN].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(11@[634:7: (n= NOT )?])
```

In my Java code I have:

```
// Exception line
Query query = em.createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
////
query.setParameter("idTab", idTablet);
if (limit > 0) {
  query.setMaxResults(limit);
}
if (dateFrom != null) {
  query.setParameter("startDate", dateFrom, TemporalType.DATE);
   if (dateTo == null) {
     dateTo = new Date();
   }
   query.setParameter("endDate", dateTo, TemporalType.DATE);
}
messages = (List<MessageEntity>) query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not SELECT *?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting any fields and you are missing the field for your date comparison. Try -

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Message m
WHERE m.tabId = :idTab
AND date_field BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
ORDER BY m.id DESC
```